# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre estas formas de cancelar eventos en JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Si tengo un formulario y le asigno una función al evento *submit* así:

```js
$('#miForm').on('submit',hazAlgo);

function hazAlgo(evento) {
  console.log('Me han pulsado');
  // ... 
  return false; //evito el submit
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="miForm" action="#">

  <button>Púlsame</button>
</form>
```

He visto que hay varias formas de evitar que ocurra el submit:

1. Que la función hazAlgo devuelva `false`.
2. Que la función hazAlgo llame a `evento.preventDefault()`.
3. Que la función hazAlgo llame a `evento.stopImmediatePropagation()`.

¿Cuáles son las diferencias entre estas tres? o ¿Cuándo se debe llamar a cada una?

Comment: Me gusto la pregunta. Google un poco y encontre [esta respuesta en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5302939/7291849), en la que compara `return false`, `preventDefault `, `stopPropagation` y `stopImmediatePropagation`.

Comment: @ManucoBianco Otra más: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042120/in-javascript-event-handling-why-return-false-or-event-preventdefault-and

Comment: @ManucoBianco muy buena respuesta

Comment: El asunto es que alguien escriba una buena respuesta en español para tenerla aquí como referencia. La mayoría de los usuarios aquí no dominan el inglés y  enlazarles a la versión anglosajona no les ayuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depende de lo que quieras hacer, si bien que el hecho de que la funcion `hazAlgo()` devuelva `false` es prácticamente lo mismo que que llamar a `event.preventDefault()` y `event.stopPropagation()` (que no lo mencionas), no es lo mismo que llamar a `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`.

Ahora entro a hablar de los detalles:

- **Que la función `hazAlgo()` devuelva `false`**: tendrá las siguientes consecuencias. Parará la *capilaridad* (o `bubbling`) del evento, evitando que se disparen los `eventListener` de los elementos que contengan a quien dispara el evento. Parará la *acción por defecto* del evento (en un formulario, por ejemplo, que se envíe) y NO detendrá la ejecución de los demás `eventListener` que haya para ese elemento.

```js
const preventMe = () => false;
const printMeA = () => {
  // Se ejecutará porque devolver false no previene los eventListeners del mismo elemento
  console.log('Me han pulsado, soy el enlace')
};
const printMeDiv = () => {
  // No se ejecutará porque devolver false previene la capilaridad
  console.log('Me han pulsado, soy el div')
}

$('a').on('click', preventMe);
$('a').on('click', printMeA);

$('div').on('click', printMeDiv);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com">Púlsame</a>
</div>
```

- **Que la función `hazAlgo()` llame a `event.preventDefault()`**: tendrá las siguientes consecuencias. **NO** parará la capilaridad del evento, así que los `eventListener` de los elementos que lo contengan **sí se ejecutarán**. Parará la *acción por defecto* evento y **NO** dentendrá la ejecución de los demás `eventListener` que haya para este elemento.

```js
const preventMe = (e) => {e.preventDefault()};
const printMeA = () => {
  // Se ejecutará porque llamar a e.preventDefault() no previene los eventListeners del mismo elemento
  console.log('Me han pulsado, soy el enlace')
};
const printMeDiv = () => {
  // Se ejecutará porque llamar a e.preventDefault() no previene la capilaridad
  console.log('Me han pulsado, soy el div')
}

$('a').on('click', preventMe);
$('a').on('click', printMeA);

$('div').on('click', printMeDiv);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com">Púlsame</a>
</div>
```

- **Que la función `hazAlgo()` llame a `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`**: tendrá las siguientes consecuencias. Detendrá la *capilaridad* del evento, evitando que se disparen los `eventListeners` de los elementos que contengan a quien dispara el evento. **NO** detendrá la *acción por defecto* del evento(es decir, si es un enlace, continuará con la acción del enlace) y detendrá la ejecución de los demás `eventListener`.

```js
const preventMe = (e) => {e.stopImmediatePropagation();};
const printMeA = () => {
  // NO se ejecutará porque e.stopImmediatePropagation previene los eventListeners del mismo elemento
  console.log('Me han pulsado, soy el enlace')
};
const printMeDiv = () => {
  // No se ejecutará porque e.stopImmediatePropagation previene la capilaridad
  console.log('Me han pulsado, soy el div')
}

$('a').on('click', preventMe);
$('a').on('click', printMeA);

$('div').on('click', printMeDiv);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com">Púlsame</a>
</div>
```

- **Que la función `hazAlgo()` llame a `event.stopPropagation()`**: No la mencionas, pero la pongo como bola extra. Ocurrirá lo siguiente. Detendrá la `capilaridad` del evento, **NO** prevendrá la *acción por defecto* del evento y **NO** prevendrá los demás `eventListeners` del elemento.

```js
const preventMe = (e) => {e.stopPropagation();};
const printMeA = () => {
  // Se ejecutará porque e.stopPropagation NO previene los eventListeners del mismo elemento. Lo pongo en alert en lugar de console.log para que se aprecie
  alert('Me han pulsado, soy el enlace')
};
const printMeDiv = () => {
  // No se ejecutará porque e.stopPropagation previene la capilaridad
  console.log('Me han pulsado, soy el div')
}

$('a').on('click', preventMe);
$('a').on('click', printMeA);

$('div').on('click', printMeDiv);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com">Púlsame</a>
</div>
```

Dicho todo esto, podría resumirse en la siguiente tabla:

```
| Acción                       | DetieneCapilaridad | Detiene Acción por Defecto | Detiene acciones sobre el mismo elemento |
|------------------------------|:------------------:|:--------------------------:|:----------------------------------------:|
|       devolver `false`       |         Sí         |             Sí             |                    No                    |
|      e.preventDefault()      |         No         |             Sí             |                    No                    |
|      e.stopPropagation()     |         Sí         |             No             |                    No                    |
| e.stopImmediatePropagation() |         Sí         |             No             |                    Sí                    |
```

Comment: Estupenda respuesta, muchas gracias. La tabla final es una buen sitio de consulta rápida una vez que se entienden los conceptos